# Auto-wiring Multiple implementation of a Abstract class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have been working on a spring MVC project structure where multiple concrete service classes extends from a Abstract Class. 
[image]

In my controller, i am trying to autowire the abstract class and choose the implementation based on the user choice. Here's the relevant portion of Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DashboardController {
    @Autowired
    LogAnalyzerAbstract logAnalyzer;//new LogAnalyzer();
      private static final Log logger  =LogFactory.getLog(DashboardController.class);
 ....
logAnalyzer.process();
 }
```

I want to the controller to use the implementation based on the user input and used the Abstract class LogAnalyzer reference in the further implementaion.

Is my logic valid? Can you guide me through?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you ask correctly, what you need to do is to create several Spring-MVC controllers, one for each use case, with its own base path, and to autowire there the abstract service class (or the service interface), based on the bean name of the concrete service (if you use the annotation @Service on concrete service classes, the bean name should be the name of the concrete service class, starting with a lowercase letter).

For example, something like the following:

```
@Service
public class MyFirstUseCaseService extends AbstractService {
...
}
```

and in the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/firstUseCaseBaseUrl")
MyFirstUseCaseController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myFirstUseCaseService")
    private AbstractService service;
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would result too many controllers which pretty much does the same task.